# how command substitution works

Tags: linux, bash

I am reading `man bash` man page, section `Special Parameters`:

```
   $      Expands to the process ID of the shell.  In a () subshell, it expands to the process ID of the cur‐
          rent shell, not the subshell.
   !      Expands to the process ID of the job most recently placed into the background, whether executed  as
          an asynchronous command or using the bg builtin (see JOB CONTROL below).
```

But I can not understand what is it saying.
Can someone please explain it on an example. Lets say I do:

```
mkdir -p /dir1/dir2/dir3/
cd !$
```

I end up in directory

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/
```

How exactly the second command (`cd !$`) works?

Comment: You're getting it backwards. `$!` is parameter substitution, with the special parameter `!`. `!$` is [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#History-Interaction).

Comment: `!$` is a history expansion and implies last argument of the previous command.

Comment: command substitution is `cmd1 $(cmd2)`, or `var=$(cmd)`, where the stdout of a command is captured by the shell and substituted into another command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$$` and `$!` are arguments which a bash script can make use of.

These arguments are automagically populated for you.

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "My own process id : $$"
ping -n 100 google.com &>/dev/null & 
# Here ping command is run in background -> see the & at the end.
# It detaches itself from the stdin and I have suppressed the output
# using the &>/dev/null
echo "Process id of the command last run in background : $!"
```

Which gave me the output:

```
My own process id : 812
Process id of the command last run in background : 7608
```

It is good knowing the process id of the background command in that you can do
things like below later :

```
kill -9 7608 #killing the background process.
```

Having said the above stuff, doing :

`cd $$`

doesn't make sense. Does it?

However, in the terminal, if you do `echo $$`, you will get the process ID of
the `bash` shell that is associated with the terminal itself. Yes !! the grandpa.

[image]

Also, You could make use of the `$!` straightaway in the terminal.

[image]

It gave me the the process id of the last background process that is `ls` plus the extra information whether it has completed or not. Pretty Cool. Isn't it?